How to delete/clear storage space on EBS usage after deleting AWS EC2 instances, terminating and deleting Volumes?
I deleted 2 instances and the volumes that were attached. The EC2 dashboard still shows that I only have 14.56 GB remaining of the 30 GB free trial. There's nothing active nor in use. I have tried in the cloudshell terminal sudo apt autoremove and sudo apt clean but the terminal gave the following error message sudo: apt: command not found.

I've tried searching online but have not found any resolutions.

The AWS Free Tier provides 30GB of storage for one month. That's a grand saving of $2.40 per month, so it's not worth much panic.
The 30GB can be used as:

One 30GB volume for an entire month, or
Two 30GB volumes for half a month, or
Any combination of GB and time that totals to 30 GB-months

In your case, you have consumed about half of the 30 GB-month of free storage, so you still have 14.56 GB-month of storage you can use this month to stay within the Free Tier. If you exceed this amount then you will be charged the standard rates for Amazon EBS ($0.08/GB-month depending on your region).
If you have deleted your EC2 instances and EBS volumes, then there would be no charge for EBS storage since you have remained in the Free Tier.
The console is also saying that you have used 100% of EBS Snapshots, so if you want to avoid extra charges then you should delete any EBS Snapshots you have created.

Thank you for response. That is showing a snapshot that I had but deleted. It’s showing how much I had used. I thought that once I deleted everything it would revert back to 30gb available. For clarification are you saying that even though I deleted the volumes, instances and snapshots, AWS will still show that I’m currently using that storage? Or does it show that I’ve used 15.44 GB of storage for the month and on Oct 1st will reflect 30 GB of available storages since it refreshes each month? Although it may not be much to you but every penny counts to be honest. Budgeting is very important.

Yes, that is correct. It is an allocation each month of "GB-month" which means "gigabytes for a month", reflecting both the amount of storage and the duration of the storage. It will reset the next month.

Thank you. So if I’m not using any services it should reset to an available 30 GB next month on the free tier correct?

Yes, that is correct. It will reset to 30GB-month available.

Sorry about the late reply. Thank you! You are absolutely correct!
